# Layers in dojox gfx api is groups

Tags: javascript, html, dojo, dojox.gfx

As i understand, Groups in Dojox.gfx is defined to get us layers in gfx api. Since every group is a different Z order. is it true? Or so we have any other layers applicable for gfx api?

Which is the best options for layers in grapics of Dojo?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, everything in a group is in the same z-index, and groups are at different z-indices. You can create a z-stacked graphic and using the reference each group, set the display property for a given set of groups in order to compose the graphic based on events. This way you can compose, scale, rotate, and translate the groups of the graphic using dojox.gfx.